# How to install Ubuntu Unity interface on Xubuntu?

Tags: unity, xubuntu

I wanted to try out Unity interface, but I am currently using Xubuntu. Which package should I install ?

I tried to install the `unity` package directly, but the Unity panel on the left won't show up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left panel is hidden by default. Install [ccsm](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ccsm) [image: Install ccsm] to enable you to change the Launcher's settings so it shows all the time.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

To show the launcher, all you have to do is put your mouse on the left side of the screen for a few seconds (on 11.10) or at the top left (on 11.04).

Comment: I couldn't see that image here , it's no longer available from imgur.com , could you tell me that which feature should i enable ?

Comment: @warl0ck: what image?

Comment: the one after ccsm , i see a image , which saying "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available. imgur.com"

Comment: great , after enabling Unity plugin , the interface shows up ;-p

Comment: @warl0ck: that's odd, the image (which is a software center icon, and really just acts as a button) is working fine for me.

BTW glad you got it fixed :).